# Load data on page refresh - dataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have my datatable code all working as expected as its refreshing the tables with data based on time interval. The only thing I am trying to fix is when someone refreshes the whole page, no data is loaded yet until the time interval set is triggered. Is there a way I can load data immediately only when someone refreshes the whole page, then the set interval kicks in afterwards. thanks

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

<!-- ------------------- Function to display maintenance messages ---------------------- -->
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var maintenanceTable = $('#maint-table').DataTable({
            "jQueryUI": true,
            "columns": [
                { "data": "msg" }
            ],

            "language": {
                "emptyTable": "No Maintenances Available in Table"
            }
        });

        setInterval (function(){
            $.getJSON("include/maintenance.php", function (pcheckmaint){
                maintenanceTable.clear().draw();
                maintenanceTable.rows.add(pcheckmaint.maint).draw();
                maintenanceTable.columns.adjust().draw();
            });
        }, 120000);
    });
</script>


<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

<!-- ------------------- Extract all Alerts ---------------------- -->
    $(document).ready(function (){
        var alertTable = $('#alert-table').DataTable({
            "jQueryUI": true,
            "columns": [
                { "data": "source", "visible": false },
                { "data": "host" },
                { "data": "description" },
                { "data": "priority" },
                { "data": "acknowledged"}
            ],
        });

        setInterval (function(){
            $.getJSON("data/json_data.txt", function (pcheckdata){

                alertTable.clear().draw();
                alertTable.rows.add(pcheckdata.alert).draw();
                alertTable.columns.adjust().draw();
            });
        }, 10000);
    });

        function ackbutton() {
            //e.preventDefault();
            var $this = $(this);
            var getvalues = $('#evtid').val();
            alert(getvalues);
        }
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: [Datatables JQuery Full Example And Configuration](http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/p/datatables-jquery-full-example-and.html)

Comment: Could you use a callback? 
`"fnInitComplete": this.rows.add(pcheckdata.alert).draw()` or something along those lines...?

Comment: @Edward
where do I use this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the function out of the setInterval call, and declare it as a named function. Then call that function, followed by a setInterval to that function again. This way, it calls it once, immediately, and then repeats it.

```
getData();
getMaintenance();
setInterval(getData, 10000);
setInterval(getMaintenance, 120000);

function getData()
{
    $.getJSON("data/json_data.txt", function (pcheckdata)
    {
        alertTable.clear().draw();
        alertTable.rows.add(pcheckdata.alert).draw();
        alertTable.columns.adjust().draw();
    });
}

function getMaintenance()
{
    $.getJSON("include/maintenance.php", function (pcheckmaint)
    {
        maintenanceTable.clear().draw();
        maintenanceTable.rows.add(pcheckmaint.maint).draw();
        maintenanceTable.columns.adjust().draw();
    });
}
```

Comment: This makes sense. Sorry I missed out something, I have in same code, 3 tables with different time intervals. I should be able to declare different setIntervals fro the diff tables?

Comment: You could do that, or you could put the other datatable code inside the same `getData()` function.

Comment: Thanks MS_SL, I have added the 2nd part of the code in the main case.